# Locking function body with function parameter object

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, thread-safety, methodimplattribute

Today I came across this piece of code

```
internal  object UpdatePracownik(object employee)
{  
    lock (employee)
    {
        // rest of the code 
    }

    return employee;
}
```

I was wondering if this is valid solution for locking access to function?

Wouldn't be better to use attribute

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
```

instead of this kind of lock ?

Comment: It might help to describe what are you trying to achieve?  Are you intending to lock on a specific instance of the `employee` object, or lock for all usage of `UpdatePracwnik` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends. If all threads call this method by passing the same globally visible object as parameter then they will all see the same lock and there will be no problems.

If instead each thread will call this method by passing its own object then locking is useless because they all see different locks. We must know the context in which the method is called to see if this is safe or not.

Using the synchronization method proposed by you makes the entire method body be wrapped in a `lock(this)` statement like:

```
internal  object UpdatePracownik(object employee)
{
    lock (this)
    {
        // code        
    }
}
```

which will guarantee atomicity of execution by multiple threads but may be too coarse-grain for your purposes and is generally not advisable.

Comment: I would go further and say locking on 'this' is a big no no (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2004/01/20/60719.aspx).  The problem is that code outside of your control can also lock on the instance and potentially cause deadlocks. A private member private readonly _lock = new object(); is preferable

Answer (score 1):

Using the `MethodImpl` attribute to synchronise the method is equivalent to locking on an object that is specific to the method.

This means that only one thread at a time can run the method, but there might not be a need to exclude other threads as long as they don't use the same data.

It also means that the method is synchronised by itself, but you might want to lock other methods too using the same identifier. You might for example want the method `DeletePracownik` to be synchronised along with `UpdatePracownik`, so that you can't delete one object while it's being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Locking on the employee instance is a bad idea, as is lock on 'this' both for the same reason: code outside of your control may also lock on those instances and cause deadlocks ([blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2004/01/20/60719.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2004/01/20/60719.aspx)).  It is preferable to use a private member:

```
private readonly object _lock = new object();

...

lock (_lock)
{
 ..
}
```

Furthermore you should familiarise yourself with [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).  Often you may want to allow concurrent access to certain functions, unless a write operation is in progress:

```
private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _rwLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

public void ReadOp()
{
     _rwLock.EnterReadLock();  //only blocks if write lock held
     try
     {
         //do read op
     }
     finally
     {
         _rwLock.ExitReadLock();
     }
}

public void WriteOp()
{
     _rwLock.EnterWriteLock();  //blocks until no read or write locks held
     try
     {
         //do write op
     }
     finally
     {
         _rwLock.ExitWriteLock();
     }
}
```